# Upgrade from Facebook iOS SDK 3.2.1 to 3.5 gave me an error with FBCrypto

Tags: facebook, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk, xcode4.6

After installing the new sdk I cleaned the project and build it. It fails with this message:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_SecRandomCopyBytes", referenced from:
>         +[FBCrypto randomBytes:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
>         -[FBCrypto encrypt:additionalDataToSign:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
>     "_kSecRandomDefault", referenced from:
>         +[FBCrypto randomBytes:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
>         -[FBCrypto encrypt:additionalDataToSign:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Same problem anyone? Solutions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, you need to include the security framework and the libsqlite3.dylib as stated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/).
It works now.

*edit*

Also found [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.2-to-3.5/) now...

Answer (score 9):

Jumping on this, im running into the same issue, I saw that the FBSDK needs the Security, AdSupport, etc. Here's my linked libraries:

[image]

My error is the same:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SecRandomCopyBytes", referenced from:
      +[FBCrypto randomBytes:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
      -[FBCrypto encrypt:additionalDataToSign:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
  "_kSecRandomDefault", referenced from:
      +[FBCrypto randomBytes:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
      -[FBCrypto encrypt:additionalDataToSign:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

All the other framework dependencies are good to go as far as I can tell. A Vlean->Build didn't fix it either. Thanks.

**Edit:** Got it. I needed to re Add Files to Project and check the Add to Target button.. basically XCode automagicka